# How to implement a partial custom mapping with MapStruct?

Tags: java, mapstruct

I would like MapStruct to map every property of my Object, **except for one particular one for which I would like to provide a custom mapping**.

So far, I implemented the whole mapper myself, but every time I add a new property to my Entity, I forget to update the mapper.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "cdi")
public interface MyMapper {
    MyMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(MyMapper.class);

    default MyDto toDTO(MyEntity myEntity){
        MyDto dto = new MyDto();
        dto.field1 = myEntity.field1;
        // [...]
        dto.fieldN = myEntity.fieldN;

        // Custom mapping here resulting in a Map<> map
        dto.fieldRequiringCustomMapping = map;

    }
}
```

Is there a way to **outsource the mapping for my field fieldRequiringCustomMapping** and tell MapStruct to map **all the other ones** like usual?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MapStruct has a way to use custom mapping between some fields. So in your case you can do someting like:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "cdi")
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "fieldRequiringCustomMapping", qualifiedByName = "customFieldMapping")
    MyDto toDTO(MyEntity myEntity);

    // The @(org.mapstruct.)Named is only needed if the Return and Target type are not unique
    @Named("customFieldMapping")
    default FieldRequiringCustomMapping customMapping(SourceForFieldRequiringCustomMapping source) {
        // Custom mapping here resulting in a Map<> map
        return map
    }
    
}
```

I do not know from what your `fieldRequiringCustomMapping` needs to be mapped, the example assumes that you have such a field in `MyEntity` as well, if that is not the case you'll need to add `source` to the `@Mapping`.

---

Side Note: When using a non default `componentModel` in your case `cdi` it is not recommended to use the `Mappers` factory. It will not perform the injection of other mappers in case you use them in a mapper.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.